# Is immigration connected to Brexit?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, immigration

Brexit is a highly topical supject and I have a question. Is immigration connected to Brexit? In what way?

Comment: Two people have already voted to close this question as "too broad" but did not explain why. Please note that mapohuanha is a new contributor and might not yet be familiar with the standards for questions on this website. If you consider this question too broad, please explain why it's too broad and how it could be improved to make it appropriate.

Comment: Please do your research before asking.

Comment: The reason I voted to close as too broad is because it's unclear as to what is being asked.  What do you mean by "connected to Brexit?" Are you aksing if that is the reason why people voted for it? Why it was originally proposed? Why or how it affects deals with the EU? How will immigration be affected by Brexit?

Comment: Searching for [immigration and Brexit](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brexit+immigration) finds eight other results.  E.g. [What is the rationale behind aiming for reduced immigration through Brexit?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/16513/4666)

Answer (score 4):

Two main connections:

- The ability of the UK to set an independent immigration policy was a major issue for the Leave campaign. They wanted to be able to deny entry to some EU27 citizens and to change the conditions of stay for others.
- When Brexit comes, some of this will happen. Right now EU citizens have a *right* to take a job in the UK, after Brexit they will likely have to ask for *permission* which may or may not be granted.
  British immigrants in the EU27 will be affected in a similar way.

Comment: The UK does have an independent immigration policy even inside the EU. It has full control of more than 50% of its immigration but does nothing about it, because it actually needs immigrants and can't wreck the economy just to satisfy bigots.

Comment: @user, There is simply no way to arrive at a measure of 50%. For what the UK can control, it does to extraordinary detail. If your interested, check out Expatriates exchange site on which some of us here are very active. Do a search on the 'United Kingdom' tag. The Travel exchange site also demonstrates this somewhat.

Answer (score 3):

Immigration is a subject that was used extensively to argue for brexit, although in reality it doesn't have all that much to do with the EU.

First the argument was made that levels of immigration to the UK are too high, with bogus claims being made about the effect on wages and the lack of housing being the main justifications. Eventually David Cameron, the Prime Minister who promised the brexit referendum, made an extremely unwise promise to reduce immigration levels from around 300,000 a year to "tens of thousands" a year. For reference, there are around 80,000 family reunions by immigration per year alone, before counting skilled workers, paying students and EU freedom of movement, so the goal was likely impossible to deliver and so far has not come close to being met.

It was argued that EU freedom of movement rules allowed many "undesirable" people to come to the UK, such as those from Poland and Roumania with few skills. There was also a completely false claim that Turkey was joining the EU imminently, which could result in 76 million Turks all moving to the UK for some inexplicable reason.

This kind of fear-mongering became a major factor in many people's attitudes towards the EU and brexit.

Of course, around 60% of immigration to the UK is from outside the EU, and not governed by freedom of movement. The UK government could stop it all tomorrow if it wanted to. Yet it does not, and there is no credible suggestion that it in fact might do so after brexit for some reason. In fact, many prominent brexit supporting politicians such as Penny Mordaunt (a cabinet minister) and Jacob Rees-Mogg have publicly stated that they expect immigration from outside the EU to become *easier* post-brexit.

In short, many voters had the mistaken belief that voting for brexit would reduce immigration, or was necessary to reduce immigration.

Comment: 'although in reality it doesn't have all that much to do with the EU.'. Of course, around 60% of immigration to the UK is from outside the EU, and not governed by freedom of movement.

Comment: _**Of course, around 60% of immigration to the UK is from outside the EU"**_ : Which naturally means 40% of immigration to the UK comes from inside the EU & is governed by freedom of movement, so.. not exactly an inconsequential figure, but the point that the UK hasn't done much to address non-EU immigration is fair.

Answer (score -5):

The EU has tied immigration to trade, more specifically unrestrained immigration to free trade. This is an atypical arrangement both historically and in the present-day context and, as far as I'm aware, the EU is the only entity to ever make such a correlation and apply it (or attempt to apply it to some degree) to trade agreements. What this means for the UK and some of the wealthier countries of the EU is that they may face flows of immigration for which their infrastructure, social systems, and culture are not prepared for. This can be especiallly trying on a system if there are large amounts of immigration in a very short period of time such as what has occurred with the UK in the last decade. This is directly related to sentiments that led to Brexit. It has not only put pressure on countries such as the United Kingdom, it has put pressure on countries such Romania who have in the obverse suffered severe amounts of emmigration. Because of the insistence that unrestrained immigration be tied to free trade, there are many Brexit supporters who are quite happy to give up the benefits of free trade in exchange for complete control of their immigration system.

Comment: Free movement of people being tied to free movement of goods (and, really, that's often just saying free movement of people transporting goods)? I can't imagine why they'd connect the two.

Comment: I think it is an attempt to model the member states of the EU around the concept of the United States having individual 'states'. But these are in reality fundamentally very different domains with completely different contexts. I'm not saying it's invalid. But trying to craft something together like that is going to present challenges. Tying together free movement of people to free trade is part of an attempt to do that. Maybe it will work. Maybe it won't, or won't quite work out like everybody originally envisioned, but it is without a doubt a significant factor in why Brexit has occurred.

Comment: Obviously, it is difficult and perhaps even painful for people to accept that fact. And I have my own hopes that eventually the UK will find its way back into the EU. But if there is truly going to be something like what the U.S. has done being recreated in Europe, then, like the United States, it's going to take some time, pain, and immense effort to reach that point. Anybody dreaming that it would be a liberal dreamscape that would just all fall into place... well... maybe in the Star Trek universe... but not in this timelime we are all living in.

Comment: EU Regulations for Freedom of Movement; https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2004:158:0077:0123:EN:PDF relevant quote from section (10) "Therefore, the right of residence for Union citizens and their family members for periods in excess of three months should be subject to conditions." This answer just repeats the lies of the Leave campaign. There is no right to "Unrestrained Migration" inherent in the EU's freedom of movement regulations.

Comment: @Jonita, Those 'conditions' are subject to all rulings of the EJC. As a result, no country can: 1) Refuse entry, except under exception criminal circumstances 2) Deport, except under exception criminal circumstances 3) Place any restritions on employment or access to public benefits. There are 3.7 million EU citizens living in the EU. No problem, I think this is positive. Just under 80% of those arrived in the last 10 years. That's a problem. This is not a lie. I am not exaggerrating for some irrational political reason. This is the reality that has been a major reason leading to Brexit.

Comment: @Jonita, And if we simply decide to negatively label people for pointing out facts, we risk shutting down necessary and uncomfortable discussions on topics like this. This only leads to quiet simmering bitterness and people voicing their opinions the only way they feel they can, at the ballot box. I'm a strong Remainer and voted so, but I'm completely willing to recognize and discuss some of the failings that the EU has, especially those that led to Brexit. This way, maybe we can work some of this stuff out or atleast come to a common understanding.

Comment: Link to numbers above: https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/internationalmigration/datasets/populationoftheunitedkingdombycountryofbirthandnationality

Comment: @ouflak It’s not “some attempt to model” the EU on the US – at least not for its own sake. The (or at least a) rationale for having free movement of labour when you have free movement of goods and free movement of capital is to remove/reduce the incentive to ship jobs abroad once the ability is there. Say you have a factory in the UK (capital) and you’re selling your goods to the UK, but once you have no restrictions on goods or capital then (other than the hassle of moving, and transporting the goods) there’s nothing to stop you moving abroad when you want to expand.

Comment: @ouflak Letting the workers go to where the jobs are is a beneficial compromise, once you have a system that allows the jobs to go to where the workers are, because without that compromise that is all that would happen.

Comment: @owjburnham, That's all fine. But 3 million people over a period of just ten years to an island country? You don't see any potential problems with that? Even now when we have 20/20 vision and can look back *see* what's happened? This helped create Brexit, helped inspire this question. And the truthful, yet painful, fact that maybe this has all worked out badly is why I'm getting downvotes. I know its disappointing. But if the UK could have held EU migration to reasonable levels that it could handle, the word 'Brexit' wouldn't even exist in our language. It wouldn't have even been imagined.

Comment: @ouflak You said there was no reason to link free trade with free movement of labour. My reply was solely about that.

Comment: @ouflak I disagree that anyone has been negatively label for pointing out facts. The number of EU Migrants to the UK has no bearing on what EU Freedom of Movement actually allows. It is not a fact that Freedom of movement is unrestricted. The fact that people believe it is, and voted based on it during the referendum, does not change the fact that it is untrue.

Comment: @Jontia, We can choose to ignore reality and point to vague rules, or we can face reality and try and solve these problems together. Fact: You pointed to some regulations that give allusions that EU immigration can be 'controlled'. Reality: 3 million EU immigrants in the last ten years and Brexit. We can choose to say these are 'lies' that have been 'debunked', or we can face the reality of what's *actually* happened and see if we can come up with solutions that we can all live with (preferrably solutions that are not allowed to drift along unresolved until they lead to a Brexit scenario).

Comment: @owjburnham, I did not say that there was no reason to link free trade with free movement. I pointed out that this is a very unusual thing to do historically and in the background of the overwhelming majority of existing trade agreements around the world. It is a curious link to insist on, and has often put negotiations in an untenable position, and I'm not just referring to Brexit.